# Fantasy novel with orbs on the cover. Main character grows up in a walled village

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a couple of years ago.

The main character grew up in a farm village. He was forced to live some place that was walled in. It had walls and a big circle door entering the village. I think there was some stone that might have blocked magic. Also remembering a bell ringing and they had to go meet in the town square. There was a big fight farther on in the book with a big creature. There was something about magic in the ground, maybe ley lines. There was also another battle with a powerful magician on a remote island, where the power was strong or there was an orb there.

I am also remembering another fight scene where he teams up with other magicians to go to the protagonists strong hold. The attack starts off good but then they are eventually defeated/forced to retreat. Because everything is on fire. They is a guy I vaguely remember to be the protagonist's main henchman that shows up maybe invisible.

I am also remembering something about the orb being used as a weapon because it contains power.

The picture below is quite close to the front cover, but it had more solid colors.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Roughly how old was the protagonist? Can you be a bit more descriptive about the place he was forced to live? (Was it a prison? A fortress? A walled village?) Why was he forced to live some place else, and by whom? Did he have any friends or family in the story? Were there any other notable characters you didn't mention? And what did you mean by "orbe?" Did you mean to type "orb" or something else?

Comment: This sounds very much like the wizard of earthsea, but all the features are not uncommon themes in fantasy literature.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.